# Database caching with Spring and being able to query it

Tags: java, spring, caching, jdbc, jdbctemplate

So, I have a Java EE application using Spring framework and JDBCtemplate. And, my application has to do several JDBC database read requests (no/very little writes) on the same database (which is a Postgres DB but is not normalized for a bunch of reasons) but with different sql statements (different where clauses). So, given this situation, I would like to be able to cache the database and be able to run queries on the cache, thereby saving me expensive JDBC calls. So, please suggest appropriate tools or frameworks or any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with using simple maps depending the query parameter you are using. A more viable solution is using ehcache.

Comment: I have several parameters in my database that i need to query on, together, so simple maps are not enough. I did look at EHCache but wasn't 100% sure if it fits my needs exactly. If anyone has experience with it, then please tell me if it is the right tool for me.

Comment: A lot of enterprises use ehcache. So if you have any doubt whether you can use it safely or not; rest assured, it is very good. I myself used ehcache and ehcache web in much bigger applications successfully. Go for it. The ehcache website has a lot of information which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring 3.1 or later, you can use `@Cacheable` on methods. You need to include `<cache:annotation-driven />` in your application context configuration. For simple cases you may use spring's ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean as cache manager. For more complex cases you can use ehcache via spring's ehcache adapter. Use `@CacheEvict` to reset cache.

Comment: I am not a 100% sure, but it seems like @Cacheable is to be used for caching of method returns ie if the method is called with same parameters then it makes sense and so the same earlier cached result is returned. But in my case I don't expect my DAO functions to be called with same parameters, in fact they will most likely be called with different different parameters each time (resulting in different different sql queries needing to be fired) and so caching of methods doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think caching of the database makes sense so that if there is a system to be able to query with different different query statements on this cached database, then application's performance is improved.

Comment: If you use @Cacheable for: someMethod(String someArg), someArg value will be the key in your cache. It doesn't require the same parameter every time. If you pass parameter you had passed before, method will return value from cache.

Comment: Yeah, exactly if I pass in exactly the same argument, then only I get the benefits of fast retrieval from the cache. But, in my application, the argument is never going to be the same. So, I would like to cache the entire DB and run different different queries on that cached version.